# ClassCastException handling

Tags: java, exception, classcastexception

I have a legacy code that looks like this,

```
///
....
List<Object[]> reportResults = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
reportResults = query.getResultList();
logger.info("reportResults ==== "+reportResults.toString());
workbook = expService.exportExcel(fileName, reportResults, reportHeaders);
...///
```

So when the resultset is more than 1 column then logger prints '[[Ljava.lang.Object;@391472f5] ' like an object.
When the reportResult is only 1 column then results look like this, '[USA, EUROPE]' when its 1 column 1 row it looks like '[USA]'

The problem is when I iterate with the reportResults in the below method. reportData parameter is nothing but reportResults below.
The inner for loop throws '**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;**' when reportData is just 1 column. How can I handle so it works for all the cases.

```
public XSSFWorkbook exportExcel(String reportName, List<Object[]> reportData, String headers) throws Exception {
 ...///

System.out.println("... "+reportData.size());
for (int i = 0; i<reportData.size(); i++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
    rownum++;
    System.out.println("....... "+reportData.get(i));
    for (int j = 0; j < reportData.get(i).length; j++) {
        cell = row.createCell(j); 
        Object oCellValue = reportData.get(i)[j];
        if (oCellValue != null) {
            String className = oCellValue.getClass().getName();
            if (className.equals(Timestamp.class.getName())) {
                CellStyle cStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                cStyle.setDataFormat((short)14);
                Timestamp tsValue=(Timestamp)oCellValue;
                Date dtValue = new Date(tsValue.getTime());
                cell.setCellValue(dtValue);
                cell.setCellStyle(cStyle);
            } else {
                cell.setCellValue(""+oCellValue);
            }
            
        } else {
            cell.setCellValue("");
        }                                                    
    } 
}
...//
}
```

So the 1st line sysout prints size as 1. It gets into the loop and prints the 2nd sysout as 'USA'.
reportData.get(i) -> this is supposed to be a object and in my case for this scenario its 'USA'.

Please let me know how I can get rid of this exception and handle the same for all cases. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The problem appears to be that your reportData List<Object[]> actually contains (String) elements. `public XSSFWorkbook exportExcel(String reportName, List<Object[]> reportData, String headers) throws Exception {`

Comment: And in general, ClassCastExceptions are exceptions that you need to fix and remove for your code. In terms of Exception handling, this contrasts (at least for me) if you tell them "enter a number" and they enter letter A

Comment: @ControlAltDel I agree but that is what query.getResultList(); gives me. Is there a way to handle all the cases in these scenarios?

Comment: `[[Ljava.lang.Object` tells me you actually have a `List<Object[][]>`. You can treat it as a `List<Object>`, and do checks to see what type it actually is.